# C++ subcommand-like argument parsing

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a program in C++ that is expected to behave like SVN, or systemctl, or some other tools:

```
./a.out SUBCOMMAND [OPTION]... arguments-for-the-subcommand
```

An example would be something like the following:

```
./a.out remove --recursive directory1 directory2
```

The *--recursive* option is only valid for the **remove** subcommand.

I'm currently using Boost.ProgramOptions, and have had no luck in my tries (the only thing I have right now is a program that accepts arguments the GNU getopt way). Although I would prefer something wide-tested, there's no problem in switching to another library if it is portable and does its job properly.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if the question is not well explained.

Best regards,
Kalrish.

P.S.: Not sure if this is of any help, but I'm currently using GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry; updated. I forgot to write the actual question because I'm so lost that I'm even not sure what's the name for what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should actually pretty simple with Boost program-options, as you then easily can construct multiple option lists.

You create one for each sub-command, and then check `argv[1]` to see what the subcommand is and use the correct option list.

Comment: It works now, thank you. But, isn't there any more elegant solutions? Maybe another library? I'm looking at TCLAP now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a header-only C++ library [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11).
Basic usage on sub-command:

```
CLI::App* sub = app.add_subcommand("sub", "This is a subcommand");
```